# Discriminant function for diagonal LDA

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, discriminant-analysis

I have a question on diagonal LDA in the book ["Elements of statistical learning"](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/) by Hastie, Tibshirani et al. 
On page 652, it says

> The discriminant score of the diagonal-covariance LDA for class $k$ is $$ \delta_{k}(x)= - \sum_{j=1}^{p} \dfrac{(x_{j}-\bar{x}_{kj})^{2}}{s_{j}^{2}} + 2 \log \pi_{k},  $$ [see (4.12) on page 110].

First thing I'm wondering about is the fact that (4.12) is the discriminant function of QDA and not of LDA, I thought diagonal LDA is based on LDA?

Nevertheless, this is (4.12):

> $$ \delta_{k}(x) = - \frac{1}{2} \log |\mathbf{\Sigma}_k| - \frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_k)^T\mathbf{\Sigma}_k^{-1}(x-\mu_k)+\log \pi_k $$

$\mathbf{\Sigma}_k$ is the covariance matrix of each class $k$.
For the transformation below I used $\mathbf{\Sigma}_k = \mathrm{diag}(\sigma_j^2) \; \forall k$.

So now I would like to justify why dLDA has the above discriminant function. 
With what I know, I was able to transform (4.12) into

$$\delta_{k}(x) = - \frac{1}{2} \log |\mathrm{diag}(\sigma_j^2)| - \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{j=1}^p\frac{(x_j-\mu_k)^2}{s_j^2}+\log \pi_k. $$

Explanation of the variables:

- $s_j$ is the Standard Deviation of the $j$th gene
- $\bar{x}_{kj}=\sum_{i \in C_{k}}\frac{x_{ij}}{N_{k}} $ mean of the $N_{k}$ values for gene $j$ in class $k$
- $C_{k}$ Indexset for class $k$
- $\pi_k$ Prior probability of class $k$, $\sum_{k=1}^{K}\pi_{k}=1$
- I think $\mu_k$ = $\bar{x}_{kj}$

So now I would really appreciate some hints how to proceed in order to transform some more so I end up with the discriminant function of dLDA.

Comment: What does your $\boldsymbol\Sigma = \sigma_j^2 I$ formula mean? Is it $\boldsymbol\Sigma_k$ for all $k$? If so, what does $\sigma_j^2 I$ mean? Diagonal matrix with $\sigma_j^2$ on the $j$-th place on the diagonal? If so, you cannot write it like that. Maybe $\operatorname{diag}(\sigma_j^2)$ or something like that.

Comment: @amoeba yes, I forgot to state that it's used for all $k$. And also true, it's $diag(\sigma_j^2)$, I will edit it

Comment: All right. Can't you compute the determinant of $\operatorname{diag}(\sigma^2_j)$?

Comment: Err, I haven't thought about this yet. In what way would it help me? I'm mostly confused by the $\frac{1}{2}$ in front of the sum, that's not there anymore later and also I don't know how to handle the $log$ of the Matrix...

Comment: It's log of the determinant, that's what vertical bars mean.

Comment: Thank you! That's a hint I definitely needed. It gets me to $\delta_k(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{p}log(\sigma_j^2)-\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{p}\frac{(x_j-\mu_k)^2}{\sigma_j^2}+log\pi_k$. Then further I could $\delta_k(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{p}(log(\sigma_j^2)+\frac{(x_j-\mu_k)^2}{\sigma_j^2})+log\pi_k$... Also I'm not sure anymore if $\mu_k = \bar{x}_{kj}$, because $\bar{x}_{kj}$ is the mean of the $j$th gene and I think $\mu_k$ is the mean over all genes in class $k$.

Comment: You appear to be are quite confused. $\mu_k$ is a VECTOR, and its element $j$ is the mean in class $k$ of gene $j$. $\bar x_{kj}$ is a NUMBER: the mean in class $k$ of gene $j$. So $\mu_k$ consists of $\bar x_{kj}$ as elements.

Comment: Unfortunately I am very confused, that's true. So it's actually $ \delta_{k}(x) = - \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{j=1}^p (log(\sigma_j^2) +\frac{(x_j-\bar{x}_{kj})^2}{s_j^2})+log \pi_k$.

Comment: Yes but it's better to leave the two sums, don't combine them into one. Now observe that the first sum is a constant that is the same for all $k$. So it can be left out, because the point of discriminant functions is to compare values for different $k$. Then observe that you can multiply the whole thing by 2. Then you are done.

Comment: The multiplication by 2, why is that okay? Because it doesn't matter if I compare $\delta_k(x) \; \forall k$ or $2*\delta_k(x) \; \forall k$?

Comment: Exactly.$\,\,\,$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve my problem thanks to amoeba's comments.

My first Transformation got me to:

$\delta_{k}(x) = - \frac{1}{2} \log |diag(\sigma_j^2)| - \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{p} \dfrac{(x_{j}-\mu_k)^{2}}{\sigma_{j}^{2}}+\log \pi_k $

Because $\mu_k$ is the vector $(\bar{x}_{k1},...,\bar{x}_{kp})^T$ with $\bar{x}_{kj}$ being the mean of the $j$th gene in class $k$, it actually should have been $\delta_{k}(x) = - \frac{1}{2} \log |diag(\sigma_j^2)| - \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{p} \dfrac{(x_{j}-\bar{x}_{kj})^{2}}{\sigma_{j}^{2}}+\log \pi_k $.

The term $- \frac{1}{2} \log |diag(\sigma_j^2)|$ means $- \frac{1}{2} \log det(diag(\sigma_j^2))$ which is a constant. As the covariance matrices of all classes are equal, this constant is the same for all classes. $\delta_k(x)$ is used to compute the discriminant score of each class to then compare them to each other. Hence this constant can be dropped because it changes all scores equally.

For the same reason, the remaining $\delta_{k}(x) = - \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{p} \dfrac{(x_{j}-\bar{x}_{kj})^{2}}{\sigma_{j}^{2}}+\log \pi_k $ can be multiplied by $2$ and this equals the discriminant function in the book.